# Inserting a logo at the left side of the table without changing the width of rest of the rows

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, logos

I am trying to use this table as a header for my document, the problem when including the logo, the width of the rest of the rows changes.
Possible to merge the "cells" of the table on the left vertically?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3.0cm}|p{10cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \centering
   & \centering Company name  & 22/10/2014  \\ \cline{2-1}
 \includegraphics[height=1.7cm,width=2cm]{Logo}  & \centering \textbf {Document title} & \tiny {page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}  \\ \cline{2-2}
   & Author & \tiny{V 1.0} \\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the logo in the table you can use `\multirow`:

[image]

### Notes:

- You should add a `\noindent` before the `tabular` environment.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.0cm}|p{10cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \centering
    \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[height=1.7cm,width=2cm,keepaspectratio]{../images/EiffelWide}} & \centering Company name  & 22/10/2014  \\ \cline{2-1}
  & \centering \textbf {Document title} & \tiny {page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}  \\ \cline{2-2}
   & Author & \tiny{V 1.0} \\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoups Peter, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You don't need to use `multirow` simply move the image before the table.
You can use `adjustbox` to vertically centre the image.

Don't specify both `height` and `width` to `\includegraphics` unless you also use `keepaspectratio` or the image will be distorted.

Size commands like `\tiny` to not take an `{}` argument.

`\cline` numbers need to be in ascending order (but I just used `\hline` here).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}


\begin{document}
 \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2cm]{Logo}%
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{10cm}|>{\tiny}p{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
   Company name  & 22/10/2014  \\ \hline
  Document title & page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} \\ \hline
   Author & \tiny V 1.0 \\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Carlisle, but is it possible to keep the logo in the table?I need to use later as a header.

Comment: yes you could use multirow or simpler just hide its height with `\smash{\includegraphics[...]{..}}`