# Place a figure next to a table

Tags: floats

I hope someone can help me how can take a picture next to a table (at \parbox there is a fault).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfarrows}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,includefoot,nohead}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Az alábbi táblázat az összetartozó reakcióidő és konverzió (x) adatokat tartalmazza.}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\parbox{6cm}{
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{t/min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{x/\%}\\
\hline
1 & 25,6\\
2 & 31,4\\
3 & 36,2\\
4 & 39,1\\
5 & 41,2\\
6 & 44,1\\
7 & 47,6\\
8 & 51,7\\
9 & 55,9\\
10 & 56,9\\
15 & 61,8\\
20 & 63,4\\
25 & 64,1\\
30 & 64,8\\
35 & 65,2\\
40 & 65,3\\
45 & 65,7\\
50 & 66,0\\
55 & 66,3\\
60 & 66,2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:xt}
\end{table} }
\parbox{6cm}{
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6cm,clip]{konverzio_par_adat.pdf}
\def\baselinestretch{1}
\caption{A fenti ábrán az összes mérési pontból kapott nyomás-hőmérséklet adatpárokból számolt konverziós értékek láthatók.}
\label{fig:konvpar}
\end{center}
\end{figure}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarise yourself further with our format. What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Does [Inserting a logo at the left side of the table without changing the width of rest of the rows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208530/inserting-a-logo-at-the-left-side-of-the-table-without-changing-the-width-of-res/208536#208536) answer your question?

Comment: Firstly, sorry, I didn't know the formulas.Thank you the correction.It's too long text to write it down.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfarrows}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float,caption}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,includefoot,nohead}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{Az alábbi táblázat az összetartozó reakcióidő és konverzió (x) adatokat tartalmazza.}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
t/min & x/\%\\
\hline
1 & 25,6\\
2 & 31,4\\
3 & 36,2\\
4 & 39,1\\
5 & 41,2\\
6 & 44,1\\
7 & 47,6\\
8 & 51,7\\
9 & 55,9\\
10 & 56,9\\
15 & 61,8\\
20 & 63,4\\
25 & 64,1\\
30 & 64,8\\
35 & 65,2\\
40 & 65,3\\
45 & 65,7\\
50 & 66,0\\
55 & 66,3\\
60 & 66,2\\
\end{tabular}

\label{tab:xt}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=6cm,clip]{konverzio_par_adat.pdf}
\rule{6cm}{1cm}% in place of the image
\def\baselinestretch{1}
\captionof{figure}{A fenti ábrán az összes mérési pontból kapott nyomás-hőmérséklet adatpárokból számolt konverziós értékek láthatók.}
\label{fig:konvpar}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code adapted to adding an image to the right hand side:

[image]

## Notes:

- The `[showframe]` option was applied to [the `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry)
  was just to show the page margins.
- I tried to leave you code as comments so you could see the changes.
- This is similar to David Carlisle's answer but uses a `parbox` instead of `minipage`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfarrows}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\geometry{showframe,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,includefoot,nohead}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
%\begin{center}
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-6cm\relax}{\centering%
\captionof{table}{My table caption.}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{t/min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{x/\%}\\
\hline
1 & 25,6\\
2 & 31,4\\
3 & 36,2\\
4 & 39,1\\
5 & 41,2\\
6 & 44,1\\
7 & 47,6\\
8 & 51,7\\
9 & 55,9\\
10 & 56,9\\
15 & 61,8\\
20 & 63,4\\
25 & 64,1\\
30 & 64,8\\
35 & 65,2\\
40 & 65,3\\
45 & 65,7\\
50 & 66,0\\
55 & 66,3\\
60 & 66,2\\
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
\label{tab:xt}}%
%\end{table}%
%
\parbox{6cm}{%
%\begin{figure}[h!]
%\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6cm,clip]{../images/EiffelTall}
%\def\baselinestretch{1}
\captionof{figure}{My figure caption.}
\label{fig:konvpar}
%\end{center}
%\end{figure}%
}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\parbox` and `minipage` share about 99% of their code:-)

Comment: Thank you very much, as well.It works but you deleted some usepackage which are important in our language. Thank you the ideas, but use of'showframe' makes the xyz.pdf ugly.

Comment: But it's not problem if it is deleted when the file is in the final version.